# How can I split one shared memory into 3 different sized mmap pointers in C?

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

If I have one shared memory segment of size 1024, how do I mmap three different sized regions of it? I tried the following, but got a seg fault. I think something is not aligned correctly but I can't seem to isolate where.

```
fd = shm_open(NAME, FLAGS, MODE);
ftruncate(fd, 1024);
addr0 = mmap(NULL, 50, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 0);
addr1 = mmap(NULL, 100, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 50);
addr2 = mmap(NULL, 874, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 150);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Adam Martin notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293010/364696), offsets must be multiples of the page size. But you probably don't need three separate `mmap`s, and could just `mmap` once and use pointers to different offsets of that single mapping:

```
fd = shm_open(NAME, FLAGS, MODE);
ftruncate(fd, 1024);
addr0 = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 0);
addr1 = (void*)((char*)addr0 + 50);
addr2 = (void*)((char*)addr1 + 100);
```

Just remember to only call `munmap` on `addr0` (at which point all three pointers become invalid). Alternatively, you `mmap` from the same start point three times, and adjust each pointer individually (which would allow you to `munmap` each value individually, just make sure to do so on the original pointer, not the adjusted pointer):

```
fd = shm_open(NAME, FLAGS, MODE);
ftruncate(fd, 1024);
addr0 = mmap(NULL, 50, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 0);
char *const baseaddr1 = mmap(NULL, 150, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 0);
char *const baseaddr2 = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROTS, FLAGS, fd, 0);
addr1 = (void*)(baseaddr1 + 50);
addr2 = (void*)(baseaddr2 + 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your offset (last argument to `mmap`) must be a multiple of page size [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).  Also `fruncate` should be `ftruncate`, though I assume you introduced that typo copying this over, otherwise your code shouldn't compile.